# How strict is Air India with hand luggage and personal items?

Tags: hand-luggage, air-india

I will fly CPH-DEL-HYD in a few days with Air India. When travelling for business, I usually bring a Samsonite roller bag within the max dimensions for hand luggage and then a shoulder bag with a laptop, headset and wallet.

So far, I've been questioned only once regarding the laptop bag. And that was at check in and not at the gate so it wasn't a problem.

Is Air India strict with the hand luggage or will I get away with both my shoulder bag and the roller bag?

Comment: Economy/Business/First ? If in economy prepare for some trouble. Considering most Indian passengers on AI flights have overweight luggage you might be fine.

Comment: I'll fly economy, many airlines specifies max dimensions for the personal item, Air India just seem to list the item types

Comment: You should be fine. And is the whole trip on AI or only DEL-HYD section ?

Comment: It's SAS ARN-CPH and then AI

Comment: Perhaps you could post an answer telling us what happened for the benefit of other travellers.

Comment: I ended being delayed more than 36 hours in CPH before buying a new ticket with BA so I can't really tell

Answer (score 1):

The same rules apply to pretty much all airlines. If you can bring your stuff with one then you should have no problems with any other.

**In addition to** your carry-on and bag/backpack you are **also** allowed to bring things from the tax-frees.

[image: Girl with a lot of bags]

Comment: great pic!!! ;)